# ActionScript 3 Cant see Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

When I play my game it does not show my _Player Movieclip, but it does collide with the ground which is very confusing. So I believe the movieclip is there but not showing the texture/Sprite.

I think the problem is in "function Spawn" (First Function).

```
 public class PewdyBird extends MovieClip
{

    //Player variables
    public var Up_Speed:int = 25;
    public var speed:Number = 0;
    public var _grav:Number = 0.5;
    public var isJump:Boolean = false;
    public var Score:int = 0;
    public var Player_Live:Boolean = true;
    public var _Player:Player = new Player();
    //Other variables

    //Environment variables
    var Floor:int = 480;
    var Clock:Number = 0;
    var Clock_restart:Number = 0;
    var Clock_ON:Boolean = false;
    var Clock_max:int = 15;
    var Player_Stage:Boolean = true;
    private var _X:int;
    private var _Y:int;
    private var hit_ground:Boolean = false;
    private var width_BG:int = 479;

    //SPAWN
    function Spawn(e:Event){
        _Player.x = 200;
        _Player.y = 200;

        stage.addChild(_Player);
    }

    //Keyboard Input
    private function KeyboardListener(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
            Clock = Clock_restart;
            Clock_ON = true;
            isJump = true;

            if(isJump){
                _Player.gotoAndPlay("Fly");
                speed = -Up_Speed;
                isJump = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Mouse Input & Spawn Listener
    private function MouseListener(m:MouseEvent){
        if(MouseEvent.CLICK){
            Clock = Clock_restart;
            Clock_ON = true;
            isJump = true;

            if(isJump){
                _Player.gotoAndPlay("Fly");
                speed = -Up_Speed;
                isJump = false;
            }   

        }
    }

    //Rotation Fly
    function Rot_Fly(){

        if(Clock < Clock_max){
            _Player.rotation = -15;

        }else if(Clock >= Clock_max){

            if(_Player.rotation < 90){
                _Player.rotation += 10;

            }else if(_Player.rotation >= 90){
                _Player.rotation = 90;

            }

        }   
    }
    //END

    //Update Function
    function enter_frame(e:Event):void{
        Rot_Fly();

        //Clock 
        if(Clock_ON){
            Clock++;
        }else if(Clock > Clock_max){
            Clock = Clock_max;
        }

        //Fall Limits
        if(speed >= 20){
            _Player.y += 20;
            return;
            _Player.gotoAndPlay("Fall");
        }
        //Physics
        speed += _grav*3;
        _Player.y += speed;
    }


    //Hit Ground
    function Hit_Ground(e:Event){

        if(_Player.hitTestObject(Ground1)){
            _grav = 0;
            speed = 0;
            trace("HIT GROUND");
        }else if(_Player.hitTestObject(Ground2)){
            _grav = 0;
            speed = 0;
            trace("HIT GROUND");
        }else if(_Player.hitTestObject(Ground1) == false){
            _grav = 1;
        }else if(_Player.hitTestObject(Ground2) == false){
            _grav = 1;
        }
    }


    //Background Slide (Left)
    private function Background_Move(e:Event):void{
        Background1.x -= 1.5;
        Background2.x -= 1.5;
        Ground1.x -= 4;
        Ground2.x -= 4;

        if(Background1.x < -width_BG){
            Background1.x = width_BG;
        } else if(Background2.x < -width_BG){
            Background2.x = width_BG;
        } else if(Ground1.x < -width_BG){
            Ground1.x = width_BG;
        } else if(Ground2.x < -width_BG){
            Ground2.x = width_BG;
        }
    }


}
```

The eventListeners are in flash it self

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enter_frame);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Hit_Ground);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyboardListener);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MouseListener);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Background_Move); 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Spawn);
```

Player.as

```
 package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Player()
        {
            super();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Spawn() function called at least once with the EventListener code?  In the code you posted, the spawn function is not called even once, so it seems like the player is never added to the stage, but still has his position checked and modified by other functions.  The problem could also be the in Player class.  Can you include the source code for that class?

Comment: The Player class has nothing in it except this "super();" Which I have no idea what that is.

Comment: If your Player class 'has nothing in it...' what are you expecting to see when you instantiate it and put the _Player object on stage? A player with nothing in it will look quite a bit like nothing.

Comment: so this will not work 

`package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 
 public class Player extends MovieClip
 {
  public function Player()
  {
   super();
  }
  
 }
}`

Comment: The Player class has no graphics code whatsoever, so the player will be invisible until you change that.

Comment: Would you like to tell me how to do that? theres already sprites and animations in the movieclip its self I thought it would work like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the movie clip's class in the library (AS3 linkage) matches the name of your player class. Also, if PewdyBird is your document class, you can move the ADDED_TO_STAGE event in the constructor. Something, like:

```
public function PedwyBird() {

    if (stage) {
      initStage();
    } else {
      addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initStage);
    }

}
```

And then you can call the spawn function in the initStage function, along with adding all the event listeners. You could also have one enter frame function instead of three.

```
private function initStage(e:Event = null){
   Spawn(); //of course, you have to remove the e:Event from Spawn declaration

   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enter_frame);
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Hit_Ground);
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyboardListener);
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MouseListener);
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Background_Move); 
}
```